# 'Expected identifier in class declaration' error

Tags: swift

I have a problem with the code:

```swift
var profileButton: some View {
    Button(action: { class.showingProfile.toggle() }) {
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
            .padding()
}}
```

Xcode says on line 2:

> 'Expected identifier in class declaration'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have implemented something like `showingProfile: Bool` in your struct, you should call it by `self` keyword (not `class`):

```
@State var showingProfile = false // Could be also Binding or else

var profileButton: some View {
    Button(action: { self.showingProfile.toggle() }) {
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
            .padding()
}}
```

Comment: Xcode says that
@State var showingProfile = false // Property wrappers are not yet supported in top-level code

Button(action: { self.showingProfile.toggle() }) { // Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

What to do?
Thanks for helping

Comment: I assumed the you know you should put this in the `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `self.showingProfile.toggle()` instead of 
`class.showingProfile.toggle()`